# Kotlin Flow missing many trivial functions like any(), distinct()

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, project-reactor

I'm using reactive programming in Kotlin and trying to use Flow as equivalent to Flux (with suspend functions)

I have noticed that many trivial functions are missing there.

Kotin List, Sequesnce have them as well as Flux

Flow has only `distinctUntilChanged` ( 1 1 1 2 2 1 -> 1 2 1) but why no `distinct`
Am I missing something ?

```
// distinct
flow.toList().distinct()
// is working but probably not ideal for performance
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: `distinct()` took me 7 lines in Kotlin flow. [FluxDistinct](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/FluxDistinct.java) is 600 lines long.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/lp/event-14/ "The goal is to provide only the core operators, which you can use as building blocks to implement the necessary, more tricky, operations on your own"

Comment: @GeorgeLeung Were they talking specifically about Flows in that quote? Why treat them differently than Sequences?

Comment: The quote is from page 3 of [this pdf](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/kotlin/events/kotlin14/quiz_answers/coroutines.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Writing `distnct` imperatively without using any combinators* does not take long.

```kotlin
fun <T> Flow<T>.distinct(): Flow<T> = flow {
    val past = mutableSetOf<T>()
    collect {
        val isNew = past.add(it)
        if (isNew) emit(it)
    }
}
```

As to why this is not included, I can offer a speculation.
`Flow` objects usually represent long running flows of data, often living as long as the application. `distinct` either stops emitting (if the number of elements is finite), or has to keep an ever-growing set of seen values. I cannot think of an real-life use-case where this behaviour is needed. As writing it yourself is not hard at-all, this function probably does not belong in the library.

---

Here the mutable set is confined within the `flow`. For every new `collect` call, a new mutable set will be created. This flow object is thread-safe.
In the other answer, the set is created outside the flow.** Therefore it will be shared over multiple `collect`ions. With the same values in the flow, the second `collect`ion will be empty.

---

The `any` implementation in the other answer is correct.
As it was deleted, I will quote it here.

```kotlin
suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.any(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Boolean =
    transform { if (predicate(it)) emit(Unit) }.firstOrNull() != null
```

It may be tempting to write `firstOrNull(predicate) != null`, but transforming to `Unit` is necessary. As `T` maybe nullable, we won't be able to tell whether the `null` returned is a real element or the because no element matches the `predicate`.

---

Referring to the implementation of `firstOrNull`, we can write the following imperative version.

```kotlin
suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.any(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Boolean {
    var result = false
    collectWhile {
        if (predicate(it)) {
            result = true
            false
        } else {
            true
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

---

* I cannot find a combinator that expresses this pattern. I have created [an issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2580) for this.

** Getting more computer-sciency, it is [closed over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) by the flow.

Comment: The speculation why `distinct` not included  is not correct since `reduce` exists in flow which also need all values and it returns single value and not `Flow`. sample: https://gist.github.com/ramiloif/0011fa7c0c1538a7ee770375007c2873

Comment: I don't think it's meaningful to compare the worthiness of inclusion of an intermediate operation and a terminal one. Besides, my point is, `reduce` doesn't hold everything in memory (in your example where you accumulate a single integer, it's constant memory); `distinct`, in contrast, has to hold every seen element in memory.

Comment: Real life example, I have ReactiveMongo repository that contain some data I want to getAll and then do some filter logic by 3rd party api request ( or some other stuff) and eventually get all dto.someField distinct results

Comment: Such operations like distinct over infinite flow make sense actually but should always be limited somehow. E.g. for distinct there could be a bufferSize so that we only compare incoming value with some limited history. So it's "partial" distinct, but it definitely has applications.

Comment: E.g. in my case applying even partial distinct would be a very nice optimization as I want to skip duplicates from consuming, but skipping them is not necessary.